# Simple delegate example for iOS not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I know there are tons of questions out there about passing messages between different view controllers. I've checked them all but I can't get it working.

I've followed this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZWT0IV8FrI replacing the storyboard with a navigation controller but I run across the following issue over and over again: 'Cannot find protocol declaration for...'

Here is the code:

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>{
    //In this line above is where I get the error 'Cannot find protocol declaration for SecondViewControllerDelegate'
    IBOutlet UITextField *userNameTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *userNameTextField;

-(IBAction)goNext:(id)sender;

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize userNameTextField;


-(void)goNext:(id)sender{

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    secondVC.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];   
}

-(void)done:(NSString*)name{

    NSLog(@"BACK in firstVC");
    userNameTextField.text = name;
}

@end
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)done:(NSString*)someText;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UITextField *someText;
    IBOutlet UIButton *returnButton;
    id delegate;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *someText;

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize someText;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

-(void)goBack:(id)sender{

    [self.delegate done:someText.text];

    FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstVC animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `SecondViewController` `goBack` implementation you are creating a new `FirstViewController` rather than popping your navigation controller, code should read...

```
-(void)goBack:(id)sender{

    [self.delegate done:someText.text];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

And also in your `SecondViewController.h` remover this #import "FirstViewController.h" as it is no longer needed and could be confusing the compiler

Comment: In your `SecondViewController.h` remover this `#import "FirstViewController.h"` as it is no longer needed and could be confusing the compiler

Comment: I'll just update this answer to include that fact, as you need to do both, i.e. remove the .h and also pop to the view controller

Answer (score 2):

Your protocol name is EYSSecondViewControllerDelegate:

```
@protocol EYSSecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
```

but you call it SecondViewControllerDelegate in two places:

```
@interface EYSFirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>{...
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;...
```

Make sure that the name match and it should works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my class prefix to add some clarity. It's edited now.

Comment: On which iOS are you? Try remove id delegate; and @synthesize delegate = _delegate; it should help.

Comment: @Greg iOS7. I've done what you suggested, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Try clear your project, restart Xcode and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

In **SecondViewController.h**

remove line `id delegate;`

In **SecondViewController.m**

Update code -> `[delegate done:someText.text];` 
**'self.'** remove
Try it

Comment: Done, but I still have the same issue.